# Could I fix this printer by myself?

Tags: printer

I've been using this printer for about 6 years. Changed a lot of cartridges, which I would fill out myself with a syringe. This is the first time I get this error.

[image: The ink absorber is almost full. [...]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling the error message produces links to the guides like [this](http://www.inktechnologies.com/blog/cleaning-canon-waste-ink-absorbers/).

> Many Canon ink printers, namely photo printers, have a simple process
>   for cleaning the ink waste absorber.

The generic description of the procedure:

> Lift the plastic lid to reveal the internal components of the machine.
>   Be sure to wait a few seconds while the ink carriage automatically
>   slides out of the way. Locate the black rubber frame that holds the
>   dual absorber pads and pull it until you feel it detach from the
>   machine. Once it detaches, pull the assembly slightly to the left and
>   then lift it out.  At this point, unplug the power supply. Remove the
>   two pads from the frame and place all three parts into a container of
>   warm, soapy water.  Let them sit for a while until the dried ink has
>   loosened, then gently scrub each piece. Let the pads and frame sit on
>   a paper towel or newspaper until each is COMPLETELY dry. Place the
>   pads back into the slots in the frame and reinstall the frame into its
>   spot on the right side of the printer.

You might want to look for a video specific to your model (PIXMA MP220) or the model line (MP Series) for more specific instructions.

Once you are finished, you will need to reset the error message.

1. Power off printer
2. Hold Resume button then press and hold POWER, the beeper will sound once.
3. Hold POWER and release RESUME
4. Press RESUME twice, then release all buttons
5. When the indicator lights steady, press RESUME three or four times. The indicator should be orange.
6. Press Power to set data

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get the parts but it is a very messy job.  Many manufacturers will not sell these parts as they want an authorized servcei centre to install.

You will alos want to get a good manual that details the dis-assembly as there are usually a fair number of parts that need to be removed.  And then properly replaced.

Some will require a realignment of print head after the reassembly.

Do this on a large drop cloth and have some good rubber gloves.

In many cases, the cost of a new, better unit makes this uneconomical.

Comment: There's nothing to replace to fix the printer. You just remove the ink pads, you rinse them and clean their "baskets", and then just put everything back together.